# Scraping the URLs of dynamically changing images from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm creating a python program that collects images from [this website by Google](https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home)

[image]

The images on the website change after a certain number of seconds, and the image url also changes with time. This change is handled by a script on the website. I have no idea how to get the image links from it.

I tried using `BeautifulSoup` and the `requests` library to get the image links from the site's html code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup('img')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag)
```

But the code returns:

```
{{background_url}}' in the image src ("ng-src")
```

For example:

```
<img class="S9aygc-AHe6Kc" id="picture-background" image-error-handler="" image-index="0" ng-if="backgroundUrl" ng-src="{{backgroundUrl}}"/>
```

How can I get the image links from a dynamically changing site? Can `BeautifulSoup` handle this? If not what library will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = re.search(r"(lh4\.googl.+?mv)", r.text).group(1)
    match = match.replace("\\", "").replace("u003d", "=")
    print(match)


main("https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What I understand from your code is the difference between parsed html from the requests library and the BeautifulSoup library. The requests library returns the value of the placeholder while the Beautiful soup library returns the name of the placeholder. Genius!

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor addition to the answer by αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη (ahmed american) in case anyone is wondering

The subdomain (lhx) in lhx.google.com is also dynamic. As a result, the link can be lh3 or lh4 et cetera.

This code fixes the problem:

```
import requests
import re


r = requests.get("https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home").text
match = re.search(r"(lh.\.googl.+?mv)", r).group(1)
match = match.replace('\\', '').replace("u003d", "=")
print(match)
```

**The major difference is that the lh4 in the code by ahmed american has been replaced with "lh."** so that all images can be collected no matter the url.

EDIT: This line does not work:

```
match = match.replace('\\', '').replace("u003d", "=")
```

Replace with:

```
match = match.replace("\\", "")
match = match.replace("u003d", "=")
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the provided answers worked for me. Issues may be related to using an older version of python and/or the source page changing some things around.

Also, this will return all matches instead of only the first match.

Tested in Python 3.9.6.

```py
import requests
import re

url = 'https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home'
r = requests.get(url)

for match in re.finditer(r"(ccp-lh\..+?mv)", r.text, re.S):
    image_link = 'https://%s' % (match.group(1).replace("\\", "").replace("u003d", "="))
    print(image_link)
```